# Angular filter in date

Tags: angularjs, date, filter

How to filter a javascript date object to only show the day value?

This input field should only display the day(dd from mm/dd/yyyy).

I think I can do this with ng-filter. But not an expert in that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/srnug/136/)

Use the [date](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/date) filter:

View:

```
<div ng-app ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    {{date | date:'dd'}}<br />
    {{date}}    
</div>
```

Controller:

```
function MyCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.date = new Date();
}
```

Comment: Thank for the replay. I tried this. but I need it in an input field. The value should be date object but the displaying should be only day(like in a number input filed).